# SQL Looking for value between two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, select

SQL Query
I have two table. A Sales table that has employees sales for the month total.

[image]

A commission table that has ranges for calculating commission.

[image]

If the TotalCalculation from Salestable is between MinAmount and MaxAmount then multiple it by Rate. Will probably be written as a stored procedure.

I have tried the between statement but unless I hardcode the actual number it does not work.

Comment: Show us your work.  Post the information as text instead of images.  Ask a question about what part of your code doesn't work.  SO is not a free code writing service.

Comment: This is a faq. Before considering posting please read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do a subquery for min-max in where clause
try this

```
SELECT *
  FROM SalesTable
  where totalCalculation between (select min(totalCalculation ) from SalesTable) and (select max(totalCalculation) from SalesTable)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join on inequality conditions:

```
select 
    s.employeeName, 
    s.totalCalculation, 
    s.totalCalculation * c.rate as calculation
from sales s
inner join commission c 
    on s.totalCalculation between s.minAmount and s.maxAmount
```